# Observables Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, observable

This is how I implemented my async observables. It runs the api every 1 minute. However when I called it on the html, its saying Cannot read property 'course' of null. Not sure how to do this.

```html
<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3" *ngFor="let course of (courses$ | async).course;">
```

```js
@Input() courses$: Observable<any>;
private courseSubscription: Subscription
getCourses() {
    this.isLoading=true;
    this.courses$ = Observable.create(observer => {
      setInterval(() => {

        observer.next(this.coursemoduleService.getCourses());
      }, 1000)
    })

    this.courseSubscription = this.courses$.subscribe(
      data => {
        this.courses$ = data;
        // console.log(data);
        this.isLoading=false;
      }, error => {
        // console.log(error);
        this.isLoading=false;
      }
    )
  }
```

I tried doing this:

```html
<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3" *ngFor="let course of (courses$ | async)?.course;">
```

but it will keep reloading the page literally. It should only reload the api without reloading the page.

Comment: First `courses$` is an observable, then you assign `this.courses$ = data` inside the subscription?

Comment: How does your `courses` object look like? Can you share a example output of the API?

Comment: @mbojko I edited the code above. Pls. check. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use rxjs built-in `interval()` function, which creates an `Observable` basaed interval. 
Simple import this: `import { interval } from 'rxjs';` version 6+,
or older use-case: `Observable.interval`.
Ex:

```js
this.courses$ = interval(1000).pipe(
      switchMap(() => this.coursemoduleService.getCourses()),
      catchError((err) => {
        this.isLoading = false;
        return of(err);
      }),
      tap((data) => this.isLoading = false),
);
```

And don't reassigne `this.courses$` variable, because this varibale holds your `Observable`.
After this your async pipe in template will works.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `this.courses$ = data;` use `this.courses = data;` and replace `courses$` with `courses` in `*ngFor`

```
this.courseSubscription = this.courses$.subscribe(
      data => {
        this.courses = data; // Updated here
        // console.log(data);
        this.isLoading=false;
      }, error => {
        // console.log(error);
        this.isLoading=false;
      }
    )

<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3" *ngFor="let course of (courses | async)?.course;">
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This does work but its giving error on subscription: courses does not exist. And page keeps reloading. If i create a variable courses: any = [] it will show nothing on page.

Comment: Did you use "?." operator on courses? (courses | async)?.course will not throw error if courses is null or undefined but (courses | async).course will.

Comment: yes I did. But the problem is the page keeps reloading every 1 sec. The page should not literally reload. I just followed the answer above. Thanks for your help!